# How to pull fields from Bloomberg using the CUSIP, not the ticker in excel?

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I am trying to pull the coupon, coupon rate and maturity date for a bunch of CUSIPS that I have.
When I use =BDP(Cusip,CPN) for example, it does not work.

I know we can do this using tickers but unfortunately all I have is a mass list of cusips. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe add an example CUSIP?

Answer (score 0):

You're using Excel.

```
=BDP(A1:A5&" CUSIP",{"NAME","CPN"})
=BQL(A1:A5,"CPN")
```

Answer (score 0):

`F1F1` is the help desk, which operates 24/7 and you would get help with that within minutes.

The link to `HELP DAPI` is `{LPHP DAPI:0:1 2571060<Go>}` but it will only work for Bloomberg users (and likely change over time).

You can do all sorts of things with the API such as directly using ISIN, SEDOL, VALOREN, CEDEL, EUROCLEAR etc., which makes it quick to get all the info you need. If you simply type the CUSIP in the command line, you would also be able to load the security.

[image]

Overall, I still think it is best to simply ask the help desk for these questions.